# What is the best way to go about putting sound into a Java application?

Tags: java, audio

What is the best way to go about putting sound into a Java application? Or is there one, it's just all personal preference or situation?

I was looking online, and I found a tutorial that included the use of the undocumented "sun.audio" (I believe it was called that) package. I looked around, and found the "javax.sound.sampled" package, which is documented, official, and *appears* to be the same thing.

So I was wondering, is there a "best", "most efficient", or "standard" way to include music in a Java application? I was looking around stackoverlow and other websites, and I found a lot of different answers pointing in multiple directions.

I suppose a follow-up question would be is one package better for short lived "effect" sounds, and one better for a more background music feel? Or is one just better overall? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should specify criteria, about what you mean by "sound" and "best"

Comment: I assume we're talking about a Java SE application (Swing or similar...). Is your audio MP3?

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is probably here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/

It gives some background, its probably best to read the first 3 pages after that. It explaines the standard way, ie. javax.sound.sampled.
Which seems to be perfectly fine and simple to play clips in audio file formats like .au, .aif, and .wav (it seems to depend on your system which it exactly supports)

One of the shortest simpelest tutorials I could find to have minimal code that plays a .wav file:
http://forum.codecall.net/topic/58228-playing-simple-sampled-audio-in-java/

When you want to play background music, its perfectly acceptable to use a .wav file but it will be a big file. If you have multiple of these you probably want to use a compressed format like like .mp3, and then there are a multitude of options.
In the tutorial link above, the first page talks about the [Java Media Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework), but it seems like not the best choice since it hasn't been updated or maintained lately.
One of the more popular libraries atm seems to be JavaFX.
It can also play audioclips (including mp3), and has a mediaplayer class to play bigger files (and loop them)
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html
a nice link seems to be:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/javafx-2-gametutorial-part-5